# Use nameof on a member of a generic class without specifying type arguments

Tags: c#, c#-6.0, nameof

```
class Foo<T>
{
   public T Bar() { /* ... */ }
}
```

I'd like to pass Bar's name to `Type.GetMethod(string)`. I can do this as `someType.GetMethod(nameof(Foo<int>.Bar))`, but that `int` is wholly arbitrary here; is there any way I can omit it? Sadly, `nameof(Foo<>.Bar)` doesn't work.

It's not such a big deal in this toy case, but if there are multiple type parameters and especially if they have `where` constraints attached to them, spelling them all out can become a task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`nameof` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx) specifically says that what you want to do is disallowed, unfortunately:

> Because the argument needs to be an expression syntactically, there
>   are many things disallowed that are not useful to list. The following
>   are worth mentioning that produce errors: predefined types (for
>   example, `int` or `void`), nullable types (`Point?`), array types
>   (`Customer[,]`), pointer types (`Buffer*`), qualified alias (`A::B`), and
>   **unbound generic types (`Dictionary<,>`)**, preprocessing symbols (`DEBUG`),
>   and labels (`loop:`).

The best you can probably do is specify `Bar` in an interface, and use `nameof(IFoo.Bar)`. Of course, that isn't an option if `Bar` includes something related to `T` in its signature (like in this specific case).

---

Another option is to create an interface where each `T` is replaced with `object`. Then the concrete type implements the interface explicitly, also implementing generic versions of the same methods.

This has a few downsides:

- Larger API surface
- More difficult and error-prone refactoring
- Losing compile-time type safety because a caller might use the `object` interface.

This probably isn't justifiable just to use `nameof`, but in some cases this strategy makes sense for other reasons. In those cases, being able to use `nameof` would just be a convenient bonus.

Comment: "for example if Bar includes something related to T in its signature" which is exactly the case for me (edited the question to include this). Ah well.

Comment: For this case, anyway, I'd rather just enter some unnecessary type arguments. For one thing, having both `T` and `object` versions of `Bar` would leave the code vulnerable to the same sort of post-renaming bugs that `nameof` was introduced to solve in the first place. If I were prepared to tolerate that, it would be simpler just to do `GetMethod("Bar")`. Life goes on. :)

Comment: @dlf Agreed. Moved contents of my comment into the answer for posterity.